# Couchbase Lite iOS: CouchCocoa's unversionedURL and CouchbaseLite's bodyURL, are they same?

Tags: ios, couchdb, couchbase, touchdb, couchcocoa

I've been working on Couchbase-Lite (aka TouchDB) for an iOS app. Meanwhile, I was trying to figure out what's new in CBL and faced following question:

`@property (readonly) NSURL* bodyURL;` //CBLAttachment

and

`@property (readonly) NSURL* unversionedURL;`//CouchAttachment

are these same? If not, what's the alternative for *unversionedURL* in new CouchbaseLite?

I'm a newbie to TouchDB, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few experiments, I've found out that Couchbase-lite's bodyURL is what I was looking for. There are minor differences between the URL string returned by unversionedURL and bodyURL But result is same. So go ahead and replace unversionedURL with bodyURL :)